# How do i install/enable php5-curl support on php 5.3.3?

Tags: fedora, yum

When i tried to install php5 curl i am getting the messages below and nothing happens.
Could anyone help me out on this ? My setup is Fedora, apache 2, php 5.3.3.

```
#yum install libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
Loading "installonlyn" plugin
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Nothing to do
```

Comment: This question is a perfect example of questions asked at http://serverfault.com/ - try asking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong package has been specified.

Try

```
yum list | grep curl -i
```

Most probably the package name is like

- curl.*
- curl-devel.*

PS : move the question to serverfault.com

Comment: curl.i386       7.16.4-1.fc7           installed
curl-devel.i386 7.16.4-1.fc7           installed

Comment: does it mean its already installed ? and how do i enable it for php5.3.3 ? thanks for your comment, i will move my issue to serverfault.

Comment: @taras - `php -r 'phpinfo();'| grep Configure` , do you specify `--with-curl` ?

Comment: Initially it wasn't with "--with-curl":

Comment: './configure' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' '--with-gd' '--with-mysql' '--with-zlib' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--prefix=/php-5.3.3' '--with-config-file-path=/php-5.3.3' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config'

Comment: After i installed curl-devel, it should auto configure php ? but i still cant get curl to work.

Comment: @taras - then specify `--with-curl` when you configure for your PHP, re-run all configuration, make, make install ... restart your apache, then `php -m | grep curl`, `php -r 'phpinfo();'| grep curl -i` **SHOULD** show correctly once curl compiled into PHP

Comment: @taras - no, you have to re-configure PHP for `--with-curl`

Comment: Where can i re-configure that ? Can you point me ? Appreciate you help :)

Comment: @taras - download PHP 5.3.3, untar the tarball, read the README first (consist most of the command), proceed with `./configure ALL_YOUR_EXISTING_OPTION --with-curl`, make, make install ..something like that, user at serverfault.com has better understanding than me, so, still having problem, remember where you should go

Comment: @taras - backup everything before proceed

Comment: Thanks to all, problem solved, i recompiled php and everything is fine now!